# grpc method call error: Failed to pick subchannel

Tags: .net, python-3.x, asp.net-core, grpc, azure-aks

gRpc Client:
Python:3.8
grpcio: 1.38.1

gRpc Server:
Dotnet core 5.0
LoadBalancer
AKS: 1.19.7

I'm getting below error when my python client calls a method.
Any help to resolve is really appreciated.

Python code snippet

```
with open('chain.pem', 'rb') as f:
        trusted_certs = f.read()

credentials = channel = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(root certificates=trusted_certs)

# 10.200.3.24 is the K8S service IP with 3 replicas
channel = grpc.secure_channel('10.200.3.24:443', credentails, options=(('grpc.enable_http_proxy', 0),))

stub = query_pb2_grpc.QueryStub(channel)

empty = google_dot_protobuf_dot_empty__pb2.Empty()
data = stub.TestMethod(empty)
```

error

```
_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "Empty update"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1625180429.368158115","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3008,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1625178894.878505214","description":"Empty update","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":201,"grpc_status":14}]}"
>
```

Comment: Using Dotnet core console app; I was able to call the method without any issue.

Comment: I’m using self-signed cert for SSL. The Chain.per file is the complete chain to the server cert. When I call same method using python client, I am getting the error.

Answer (score 7):

This is resolved now. Updating if it helps anyone out there with similar issue.
First enable gRpc trace using below two exports and then run your code see the error in detail.

```
export GRPC_TRACE=all
export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG
```

In my case, there was this below error

```
handshake failed: {"created":"@1582571630.967438000","description":"Peer 
name 10.200.3.24 is not in peer certificate", "file":
"src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl/ssl_security_connector.cc",
"file_line":55}
```

My server self-signed cert (subject:/C=US/ST=US/O=Self Signed/CN=10.100.3.250) did not have subjectAltName extension. After adding subjectAltName extension (IP.1=10.100.3.250), stuff started working fine.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to make this work on windows you need the following lines:

import os

os.environ['GRPC_TRACE'] = 'all'

os.environ['GRPC_VERBOSITY'] = 'DEBUG'